# How to deal with empty fields in Logstash

Tags: logstash

I am facing problem with Logstash KV filter:

Below is sample event:

```
2016-08-15T12:43:04.478Z 103.240.35.216 <190>date=2016-08-15 time=18:13:16 timezone="IST" device_name="CR25iNG" device_id=C2222-123 log_id=010302602002 log_type="Firewall" log_component="Appliance Access" log_subtype="Denied" status="Deny" priority=Information duration=0 fw_rule_id=0 user_name="" user_gp="" iap=0 ips_policy_id=0 appfilter_policy_id=0 application="" application_risk=0 application_technology="" application_category="" in_interface="PortA" out_interface="" src_mac=44:d9:e7:ba:5b:6c src_ip=172.16.16.19 src_country_code= dst_ip=255.255.255.255 dst_country_code= protocol="UDP" src_port=45541 dst_port=10001 sent_pkts=0 recv_pkts=0 sent_bytes=0 recv_bytes=0 tran_src_ip= tran_src_port=0 tran_dst_ip= tran_dst_port=0 srczonetype="" srczone="" dstzonetype="" dstzone="" dir_disp="" connid="" vconnid=""
```

Below is the KV filter output:

```
"@version" => "1",
"@timestamp" => "2016-08-16T13:48:30.602Z",
"type" => "cyberoam.input",
"host" => "ip-172-31-6-249",
"time" => "18:13:16",
"timezone" => "IST",
"status" => "Deny",
"priority" => "Information",
"duration" => "0",
"iap" => "0",
"application" => "",
"application_risk" => "0",
"application_technology" => "",
"application_category" => "",
"dst_country_code" => "protocol=UDP",
"recv_pkts" => "0",
"tran_src_ip" => "tran_src_port=0",
"tran_dst_ip" => "tran_dst_port=0",
"srczonetype" => "",
"srczone" => "",
"dstzonetype" => "",
"dstzone" => "",
"dir_disp" => "",
"syslog_severity_code" => 5,
"syslog_facility_code" => 1,
"syslog_facility" => "user-level",
"syslog_severity" => "notice",
"date" => "2016-08-15",
```

Problem:

```
"dst_country_code" => "protocol=UDP",
"tran_src_ip" => "tran_src_port=0",
"tran_dst_ip" => "tran_dst_port=0",
```

Above is due to empty keys "dst_country_code", "tran_src_ip" and "tran_dst_ip".

I was suggested to use mutate gsub to add default value to empty field by substituting =\w with ="".

But this never worked.

Pleas help.

Comment: Can you show the `mutate/gsub` filter you crafted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logstash kv filter issue with blank values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39389577/logstash-kv-filter-issue-with-blank-values)

Answer (score 3):

I got response from Logstash community and that worked.

```
mutate {
gsub => [ 'message', '= ', '="" ' ]
}
```

Thanks.