# Logstash kv filter issue with blank values

Tags: logstash

I am using the kv filter in my logstash configuration and I have a string that looks something like this:

```
key1="value1" key2="" key3= key4=1
```

Notice that key3 has no value; that causes key3 to be assigned a value of `"key4=1"`
how do I fix this?

Comment: This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38989998/how-to-deal-with-empty-fields-in-logstash

Comment: True. I would have preferred to see it before answering the question.

Comment: @Val should one of the two question (this one or the one you linked) marked as duplicate?

Comment: @baudsp I'd say this one since the other one already has the same answer.

Comment: @Val Well this question is easier to understand (in my opinion), so that's why I did not know which one to flag. Do you flag the most recent one (this one) or the one which might be less useful for other people (the other one)?

Comment: I understand your point and it is valid. In the end it's a matter of interpretation (i.e. which one is easier to understand or not). After flagging either one, if both questions had a link to each other, it would not matter which one is flagged, but it's not the case. feel free to flag whichever makes sense to you.

Comment: @Val ok, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be the best solution, since we're blindly replacing:

```
  mutate {
    gsub => [
       "message", "= ", '="" '
    ]
  }
```

With this filter before the kv filter, any empty space after an equal sign are replaced with two quotes, giving this result:

```
"key1": "value1",
"key2": "\"\"",
"key3": "\"\"",
"key4": "1\r"
```